# Getting "No Data available" for sql query in Cognos 10.2.2

Tags: sql, oracle, cognos-10, cognos-bi

Can anyone suggest me that how to get data in report for sql query.I am getting as "No data available" in report for the sql query " select * from all_objects where owner =: OWNER". Please help me to solve this.

Comment: what is OWNER ? did you try this script on db and did it get the data?

Comment: Hi Ersin Gülbahar, i tried the same query in SQL developer and i am getting data for this Query.Owner is parameter.But for the same query i am getting as "No Data available" in Cognos BI report.Can You please Guide me to solve this.

Comment: did you try same OWNER in oracle and cognos? and same DB ?

Comment: can you try it without parameter I mean write it hardcoded

Comment: Yes.When i tried in oracle it is giving me an error as "ORA-01008: not all variables bound" and  In Cognos ,the same query will be validated with NO errors but when i run the report i am getting as "No data available". But for the same query i am getting data after passing parameter in SQL Developer.

Comment: write here your sql script

Comment: Yes I can achieve it by  hardcoding like "SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OWNER='SYS' ; " but i want to create parameter only. Since we will be having many parameter values and hardcoding is time consuming.

Comment: do you give 'SYS' as parameter? with uppercase ? and your parameter must be string

Comment: Yes Ersin the parameter is string. I am Having parameter values as 'SYS','PUBLIC' ,'HR','MDSYS' ,'TSMSYS','SYSTEM' etc.All will be in uppercase.

Comment: Hi, Can u please help me to solve this as i am new to Cognos.

Comment: can you run this ?  select =: OWNER from dual

Comment: Hi, I tried the above sql statement.It will ask for parameter value .But after passing parameter value i am getting error as "ORA-00936: missing expression". Please suggest me.

Comment: did you try this :  ?pOWNER?  syntax

Comment: Thank you Ersin for your suggestions.But this is also giving me the same error.Please guide me to solve this.

Comment: Hi, I am getting data for the first query in oracle that is "SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OWNER=:OWNER;".There must not be any spaces between OWNER=:OWNER, else will get error as"ORA-01008: not all variables bound". But now for the same query i am getting again as "No data available" in cognos report.Please help me to solve this.